# Is there an alternative way to know when DynamoDb table descreased?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a weird problem with one of my tables in DynamoDb. When I make a petition to describe it I find that it was decreased three times today, while in the AWS console I can see only one scale down, that coincides with the one returned by `LastDecreaseDateTime` when performing a `describe_table(TableName="tableName")` on `boto3` library.

**Is there any other way to check when were the other decresing actions executed?**

Also, **is it possible that DynamoDb is fooling me someway?** I am a little bit lost with this, because all what I can see from the metrics tab in the console is that it was just decreased once. I have other tables configured exactly the same way and they work like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudTrail will record all UpdateTable api calls. Enable CloudTrail, then when this happens again you will be able to see all the api calls.

If you have scaled down multiple times with in 5 minutes you will not see that reflected in the Provisioned Capacity metrics since they have a 5 minute resolution,.

Comment: Didn't even know that it existed. Thank you so much. To complete this question/answer here there is the oficial link to check the price: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/pricing